# sticky app/ connectionstring settings through ARM PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure

am trying to use ARM to create slots and make few setting sticky.  Using Set-azurewebsite we can do that but by using ARM how can we achieve this ???

Comment: what are sticky settings?

Answer (score 0):

There is this Cmdlet called Set-[AzureRmWebAppSlotConfigName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt767963.aspx) that does exactly that.

For example, if you would like to set app settings called "AppSetting1" and "AppSetting2" and a connection string called "MyConnectionString" as Slot settings you should do the following:

```
Set-AzureRmWebAppSlotConfigName -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" -Name "myWebAppName" -AppSettingNames "AppSetting1, AppSetting2" -ConnectionStringNames "MyConnectionString"
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, but if anyone stumbles over this, you can do this with a `config` type as a nested resource in your `Microsoft.Web/sites` website definition.

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
    "name": "slotconfignames",
    "type": "config",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('siteName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "appSettingNames": [ "AppSettingKey1", "AppSettingKey2" ]
    }
}
```

Credit for this snippet to https://gist.github.com/anthonychu/9ea3aca12df863504aa4